# PHP Spread Syntax in Array Declaration

Tags: php, arrays, variadic-functions, spread-syntax

PHP supports the spread syntax for [variadic functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).

In JavaScript, you can use the spread syntax to do [this](https://jsfiddle.net/narthur/9j2cym0x/):

```
var a = [1, 2];
var b = [...a, 3, 4];
console.log(b); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However, trying to do this in PHP:

```
$a = [1, 2];
$b = [...$a, 3, 4];
var_dump($b);die;
```

Results in this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '...' (T_ELLIPSIS), expecting ']'

Is using the spread syntax this way not allowed in PHP? If so, is there an equally-as-elegant way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: No, PHP doesn't have a magic shortcut syntax: just the basic `$b = array_merge($a, [3, 4]);`

Comment: It's part of PHP  since December 2019 http://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array

Comment: It's part of PHP since December 2019 or 2018? Current date of the my comment is, 13/05/2019

Comment: It will be available in PHP 7.4.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The spread operator in [the arrays RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array) has been implemented in PHP 7.4:

```
$ary = [3, 4, 5];
return [1, 2, ...$ary]; // same as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Caveat: The unpacked array/Traversable can only have integer keys. For string keys `array_merge()` is still required.

Comment: The spread operator now supports arrays with string keys in PHP 8.1+, see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_unpacking_string_keys.

Comment: Now, no more use of array_merge() for strings in PHP ^8.1

Answer (score 18):

**Update: Spread Operator in Array Expression**

**Source**: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array

> ```
> Version: 0.2
> Date: 2018-10-13
> Author: CHU Zhaowei, jhdxr@php.net
> Status: Implemented (in PHP 7.4)
> ```

An array pair prefixed by `…` will be expanded in places during array definition. **Only arrays and objects who implement Traversable can be expanded.**

For example:

```
$parts = ['apple', 'pear'];
$fruits = ['banana', 'orange', ...$parts, 'watermelon'];
// ['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'watermelon'];
```

It's possible to do the expansion multiple times, and unlike argument unpacking, … can be used anywhere. It's possible to add normal elements before or after the spread operator.

Spread operator works for both array syntax(array()) and short syntax([]).

It's also possible to unpack array returned by a function immediately.

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
$arr2 = [...$arr1]; //[1, 2, 3]
$arr3 = [0, ...$arr1]; //[0, 1, 2, 3]
$arr4 = array(...$arr1, ...$arr2, 111); //[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 111]
$arr5 = [...$arr1, ...$arr1]; //[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

function getArr() {
  return ['a', 'b'];
}
$arr6 = [...getArr(), 'c']; //['a', 'b', 'c']

$arr7 = [...new ArrayIterator(['a', 'b', 'c'])]; //['a', 'b', 'c']

function arrGen() {
    for($i = 11; $i < 15; $i++) {
        yield $i;
    }
}
$arr8 = [...arrGen()]; //[11, 12, 13, 14]
```

**<---------------End of Update-------------------->**

First of all you are referencing the Variadic function with arrays in wrong sense.

You can create your own method for doing this, or you can better use `array_merge` as suggested by @Mark Baker in comment under your question.

If you still want to use spread operator / `...`, you can implement something like this yourself.

```
<?php
function merge($a, ...$b) {
    return array_merge($a,$b);
}

$a = [1, 2];
$b = [3,4];
print_r( merge($a, ...$b));
?>
```

But to me, doing it like this is stupidity. Because you still have to use something like array_merge. Even if a language implements this, behind the scene the language is using merge function which contains code for copying all the elements of two arrays into a single array.
I wrote this answer just because you asked way of doing this, and elegancy was your demand.

**More reasonable example:**

```
<?php
$a = [1,2,3,56,564];
$result = merge($a, 332, 232, 5434, 65);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: What about if I want to preserve keys? array_merge is not sufficient in this case.

Comment: @Facedownn did you try the code? array_merge preserves the keys. Or you meant something else?

Comment: Following example will not preserve keys causing 4 items on output, but I want only 2.
`array_merge(...[[2 => 'foo', 3 => 'bar'], [2 => 'foo', 3 => 'baz']])`
I was looking for something like + (plus)  operator for such case.

Comment: @Facedown please ask another question, this is not related to what you are asking.

Answer (score 7):

> **Below PHP 7.4**

```
$mainArray = ['element1', 'element2'];
$finalArray = array_merge($mainArray, ['element3']);
print_r($finalArray);
// Final array would be ['element1', 'element2', 'element3'];
```

> **In or Above PHP 7.4**

```
$mainArray = ['element1', 'element2'];
$finalArray = [...$mainArray, 'element3'];
print_r($finalArray);
// Final array would be ['element1', 'element2', 'element3'];
```

Answer (score 6):

In PHP 7.4 you can now use Spread Operators in array expressions.

```
$parts = ['apple', 'pear'];
$fruits = ['banana', 'orange', ...$parts, 'watermelon'];
// ['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'watermelon'];
```

Comment: Very nice! What's your source for this?

Comment: Found the proposal, looks like this isn't yet a thing, but is *likely* to be in 7.4: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array