# how to get 2 table data into single variable array in laravel?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

i have 2 tables User and subadmin consider user have 3 columns and subadmin has 2 column i want to get  3+2 (5 column) data into a single veriable array

the technique i want to use is that in user table i have id which is same in subadmin table with sub_admin_id(column) how i can use eloquent model to first link id with sub_admin_id and then into a single query get 5 column in single veriable array

here i am using to get data

```
$subadmindata = User::find($id)->get(); // [column1 ,column2 ,column3 ]
$subadmindata1 = SubAdmin::find($id)->get(); // [column1 ,column2 ]
```

**output should be**

```
$data = // [column1 ,column2 ,column3 , column4 ,column5 ]
```

note i dont want to use array merge or combine method i want to use eloquent model for my learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [`concat`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-concat) like this

```
$subadmindata = User::find($id)->get();
$subadmindata1 = SubAdmin::find($id)->get(); // it will return array of collections

$data = $subadmindata->concat($subadmindata1);
```

> **Notice** when you use `get` after `find` it stop it's jobs so there is no need to `find` here

Comment: first of all thanx for every contributor but these methods i already know is there a way i use model function for this i have seen a query User::where('role', 5)->has('ordertaker')->with('ordertaker'); somthing like this i mean use model to get data into single veriable?

Comment: you could do that if there a relation between these two tables

Comment: This code looks like wrong `$subadmindata.concat($subadmindata1)`

Comment: @Kenath i test it out after adding the answer for double checking

Comment: @Kenath not native `PHP` in `laravel`

Comment: @Joseph The syntax looks wrong for me '.' operator you can use for concat multiple strings. You can't use it like this as far as I know. `$subadmindata->concat($subadmindata1)` may work but not `$subadmindata.concat($subadmindata1)`

Comment: aha thanks for mention that i missed it out :)

Answer (score 1):

`get()` method will give you a collection not array, so you can merge two collection as follows.

```
   $subadmindata = User::find($id)->get();
   $subadmindata1 = SubAdmin::find($id)->get();

    $data = $subadmindata->merge($subadmindata1);
```

Comment: when you use `get` it returns an array of collections

Comment: first of all thanx for every contributor but these methods i already know is there a way i use model function for this i have seen a query User::where('role', 5)->has('ordertaker')->with('ordertaker'); somthing like this i mean use model to get data into single veriable?

Comment: You should use get() for get the collection and find() for a single resource.

Comment: @Joseph It returns the [collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collection_(abstract_data_type)) - not the array of collections.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use find with get(Assuming that you need a one result not all of the users). Try this. But looks like you need build the relationships correctly first. Anyway, quick answer is below.

```
$userCols = User::select('column1','col2','col3')->find($id);
$subAdminCols = SubAdmin::select('col4','col5')->find($id);
$cols = array_merge($userCols->toArray(), $subAdminCols->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use php `...` operator to to push data

example like this

```php
$subadmindata = User::find($id)->get()->toArray(); // [column1 ,column2 ,column3 ]
$subadmindata1 = SubAdmin::find($id)->get()->toArray(); // [column1 ,column2 ]
array_push($subadmindata, ...$subadmindata1);

return $subadmindata
```

ref link https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array

Comment: he asked how to make it with **laravel** collection, not the native way

Comment: @Joseph i used this because he may have different table structure so

Comment: first of all thanx for every contributor but these methods i already know is there a way i use model function for this i have seen a query User::where('role', 5)->has('ordertaker')->with('ordertaker'); somthing like this i mean use model to get data into single veriable?

Comment: `array_push($subadmindata, ...$subadmindata1)` this looks wrong use of the ... operator. You can't use this like the spread operator in typescript.

Comment: @Kenath https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419150/php-spread-syntax-in-array-declaration check this

Comment: @KamleshPaul Looks like I'm wrong. I haven't tried with the php 7.4. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @Kenath i use php 8 for my project and i used all latest feature porvided buy that and i like the language

Answer (score 0):

try this
in user model

```
public function subadmin(){
        return $this->hasOne(SubAdmin::class,'sub_admin_id');
    }
```

in controller

```
    $sub_admins = User::find($id);
dd($sub_admins->subadmin->sub_admin_id)
```