# Spread Operator for arrays with string keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

PHP supports spread operator [PHP Spread Syntax in Array Declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419150/php-spread-syntax-in-array-declaration)

```php
$ary = [3, 4, 5];
return [1, 2, ...$ary]; // same as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now I am trying a simple spread operator on 'Object' but it is failing

```php
 $a = ['a' => 1];
 $b = ['b' => 2];
 $c = [...$a, ...$b]; // Expected $c = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2]
```

Am I missing something?

> Cannot unpack array with string keys

Comment: I don't understand why you call this "Object". Apart from that, doesn't the error message already tell you what's up?

Comment: Dear this functionality will be coming in php 8.1 and so on, right now its not supported.

Comment: Even the question you linked to specifically addresses this in the answer: _"Caveat: The unpacked array/Traversable can only have integer keys."_

Answer (score 0):

php simply does not support that,,, to obtain the expected result you would need to use `array_merge`

```php
$a = ['a' => 1];
$b = ['b' => 2];
$c = array_merge($a, $b); // this will have $c = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2]
```