# Laravel Equivalent to JavaScript's ...prev

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to add an attribute to be passed in data but I would like all other attributes to stay.

```
$data = $request->all();
```

Is it possible to do this:

```
$data =[...data, 'Total'=> $total]
```

I think that ...data is for javascript. Is there an equivalent in laravel?

Comment: Does [php-spread-syntax-in-array-declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419150/php-spread-syntax-in-array-declaration) answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Spread Syntax in Array Declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419150/php-spread-syntax-in-array-declaration)

Comment: Yes thank you so much! I will test it out in a few.